# Postgres update duplicates using a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a primary key that is unique but have a secondary column with duplicate values. other tables use this primary key for linking purposes.

I want to merge duplicate values based on secondary column in all tables which the column is not null, what would be the best way going about as well if possible a example.

Table 1

```
- T1Column1(PrimaryKey)
- T1Column2 ( have duplicate values )
```

Table 2

```
- T2Column1 (primaryKey)
- T2Column2 (Some column)
- T2Column3 (Table 1 Primary Key)
```

Not sure if what I am asking is clear.

Merging all values if they are not empty using table 1 which have duplicates in.

Example

```
--Retrieve all values that have duplicates . Note Primary Is not a duplciate but i need rsaid to be unique
for r in
    select * from  importedcase where id in ( select max(id) from importedcase
    group by rsaid having count(*) > 1) order by id 
loop

    -- second loop is to merge or update the tables and then will delete the old data
    for rs in
        select * from importedcase where rsaid = r.rsaid
        group by rsaid having count(*) > 1 order by id 
    loop
        --UPDATE all tables using 
    end loop;
end loop;
```

The example is what i think should happen but not sure how to achieve goal.
NOTE -- Getting the max id from table one which will be used for the merge or update then the others will be deleted

Tables and columns

```
importedcase
id - rsaid - c3 - c4

1  - 1111  - Test  - ''
2  - 1111  - ''    - foo
3  - 1231  - ''    - ''

secondtable
id - importedcase_id - column3 - column 4

1  -   1  -  somedate   -  hasdata
2  -   2  -  test       - ''
3  -   3  -  foo        - ''
```

What my outcome should be is to have rsaid in imported case to be unique i want to update the second table with the max id from imported case aswell as use the data if its not null

Outcome can look like this

```
importedcase
id - rsaid - c3 - c4

2  - 1111  - Test - foo
3  - 1231  - ''    - ''

secondtable
id - importedcase_id - column3 - column 4

2  -   2  -  test       - hasdata
3  -   3  -  foo        - ''
```

Comment: This question isn't too clear to me.  Can you show some sample data indicating what you want to do here?  You need to show us the example, not the other way around.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: No, we are ideally looking for a couple of sample tables with data, and then the output you want in each of those tables.

Comment: Not sure if its more clear , as well as not sure how to explain it beter

Comment: Things would probably be clearer if you used consistent naming for tables and columns throughout your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the table to itself via a left join would work well. Also, making sure the right-hand primary key is higher or you'll end up with too many. I also used a group by with the MIN() function because you might have triplicates in there somewhere that you don't know about and for that you'll have 2 columns.

```
select
min(t1.keyCol)
,t1.valueCol
,min(t2.keyCol)
from yourTable t1
left join yourTable t2
on t1.valueCol = t2.valueCol
and t1.keyCol < t2.keyCol
group by t1.valCol
```